# Dragging on Different Levels

Tags: flash, oop, architecture

I have a flash project with three non overlapping panels (visual spaces) each of which contains different movie-clips. Each movie-clip in a particular panel is the child of that panel.

Now, I want to drag one of the movie-clips from one panel to another (remove it as a child from the first panel and add it to the other) without a jitter and proper drag.

What is the appropriate way to handle the drag architecturally. Should the drag be handled in all panels parent. In the panels, or the items themselves?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would handle the drag in the common parent of the panels, just because likely you wouldn't want each panel to have references to the other panels, because that isn't good encapsulation.